# Dynamically add class to Bootstrap's popover

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to dinamically add a custom class to popovers in Bootstrap 3. Every other question I found was either for Bootstrap 2.1.0 or useless.

As an example I'd like to add a custom class to the popover triggered by the next piece of code

```
<a class="newsletter-icon" href="#" alt="" title="Suscríbete al newsletter" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."></a>
```

Any idea on how to approach to a solution? Maybe using data-something, but how/what then?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I don't really think this is possible out of the box. You'll need to store the target class in the tag (e.g. `data-clazz`) and create the popover yourself in a click handler where you can easily apply the class.

Comment: You can use the `template` option of popovers: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/ceda9483723fedb04ad6221a32be028cc81c5d4d/docs/_includes/js/popovers.html#L185